# Failure to build a React Native project due to ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I can't run a React Native project. When I try to run this one, it gives me the following log and I can't get my head around this still:

```
`info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project :app
WARNING:DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Using it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`
```

I've tried clearing cache, reinstalled all the tools following documentation step by step, react native doctor shows no errors, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Which operating system are you using ? Which react-native version ? In case you are using mac os: Which shell are you using ? Did you export ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, react-native-cli 2.0.1 react-native 0.72.7, yes ambient variables are ok

Answer (score 0):

**1. Try cleaning the build or simply delete the build folder `android/build`**

• Clean build by running:

```
cd android

./gradlew clean
```

**2. Then delete node_modules and install it again**

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

**3. If your issue persists ensure your Android SDK and related tools are up to date.**

*This should resolve your problems.*

**Note:** Remember to restart your development server and rebuild the project after making these changes.

Comment: Strangely, I've followed this approach before, did it one more time now and no effect whatsoever.